# how to check the installation location of libstdc++6 in docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am unable to find where this will install libstdc++6 library in the docker image.

FROM alpine:edge

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib

**RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++6**

Comment: It's probably in `/usr/lib` or thereabouts; usually any library you install with a package manager will be installed in the system paths, and you do not need to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: thanks. it did install in the /usr/lib. with below answer i was able to verify it

Answer (score 1):

You can start an Alpine container in interactive mode and run your commands. Then you can check where they've been installed

Something like this

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine:edge /bin/sh
/ # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
/ # apk add --no-cache libstdc++6
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing libgcc (10.3.1_git20210625-r0)
(2/2) Installing libstdc++6 (6.4.0-r12)
OK: 7 MiB in 16 packages
/ #
```

Then you can check what's in the /lib and /usr/lib directory

```
/ # ls /lib
apk                    ld-musl-x86_64.so.1    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1  libssl.so.1.1          libz.so.1.2.11         modules-load.d
firmware               libapk.so.3.12.0       libcrypto.so.1.1       libz.so.1              mdev                   sysctl.d
/ # ls /usr/lib
engines-1.1                 gcc                         libcrypto.so.1.1            libgcc_s.so.1               libssl.so.1.1               libtls-standalone.so.1      libtls-standalone.so.1.0.0  modules-load.d
/ #
```

Comment: Thanks. worked. I see that its installed in /usr/lib

Comment: is it possible to install specific version libstdc++6 like libstdc++6.0.19?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Easy? No. Old Alpine packages aren't saved when a new version is made, AFAIK. If you absolutely need it, you can build it from source, but that's probably not easy. Also, if you find an answer useful on Stackoverflow, it'd be nice if you upvoted it and/or marked it as your accepted answer.